# Flexbox items won't go side-by-side in Safari 10 (desktop)

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p02fzjxu/3/).

`<profile-summary>` elements are supposed to be adjacent

Works in Chrome, FF, IE11+. But Safari 10 won't do it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/da3veswu/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be because of `profile-summary { flex-basis: 100%; ... }`, which sets the initial size of the element to `100%` width. That seems to work with your `max-width` declaration, by visually constraining the width, but still puts the flex items on their own line in safari, and does not in the other browsers.

A better way of doing that would be to remove `flex-basis` and set `flex-grow: 1`. That seems to work well with `max-width` and leaves the flex items on the same row in safari/chrome/ff.

```css
search-profiles-page {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin-left: 0;
  flex: .75;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin-left: 0;
  flex: .75;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  display: block;
  background: #f7fafa;
}

profile-summaries {
  display: block;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results profile-summaries .list {
  padding: 15px;
}

profile-summaries .profiles-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results profile-summaries .list profile-summary {
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: calc(30% - 15px);
}

profile-summary {
  /*flex-basis: 100%;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<search-profiles-page>
  <div class="xui-profile-search-results">
    <profile-summaries>
      <div class="list">
        <profile-modals>
          <div class="profiles-container">
            <profile-summary>
              <div class="profile-header">
                blahblah
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                blahblah
              </div>
            </profile-summary>
            <profile-summary>
              <div class="profile-header">
                blahblah
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                blahblah
              </div>
            </profile-summary>
          </div>
        </profile-modals>
      </div>
    </profile-summaries>
  </div>
</search-profiles-page>
```

You could also just use `width: 100%` instead of `flex-grow: 1` and it will behave the same way, but I think it's best to use flex properties if you can and `flex-grow` seems to work just fine.

```css
search-profiles-page {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin-left: 0;
  flex: .75;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin-left: 0;
  flex: .75;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  display: block;
 background: #f7fafa;
}
profile-summaries {
  display: block;
}
search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results profile-summaries .list {
  padding: 15px;
}
profile-summaries .profiles-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results profile-summaries .list profile-summary {
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: calc(30% - 15px);
}
profile-summary {
  /*flex-basis: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
  <search-profiles-page>
    <div class="xui-profile-search-results">
       <profile-summaries>
          <div class="list">
             <profile-modals>
                <div class="profiles-container">
                   <profile-summary>
                      <div class="profile-header">
                         blahblah
                      </div>
                      <div class="body">
                         blahblah
                      </div>
                   </profile-summary>
                   <profile-summary>
                      <div class="profile-header">
                         blahblah
                      </div>
                      <div class="body">
                         blahblah
                      </div>
                   </profile-summary>
                </div>
             </profile-modals>
          </div>
       </profile-summaries>
    </div>
  </search-profiles-page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `flex: 1;` to your `profile-summary`, and it should work fine on all browsers.

As per the [W3 article](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common),

> **flex: positive-number**
>
> Equivalent to flex: **positive-number** 1 0. Makes the flex item
>   flexible and sets the flex basis to zero, resulting in an item that
>   receives the specified proportion of the free space in the flex
>   container. If all items in the flex container use this pattern, their
>   sizes will be proportional to the specified flex factor.

In other words, *flex: 1* means,

```
flex-grow : 1; // this means that the div will grow in same proportion as the window-size
flex-shrink : 1; // this means that the div will shrink in same proportion as the window-size 
flex-basis : 0; // this means that the div does not have a starting value as such and will take up screen as per the screen size available for.e.g:- if 3 divs are in the wrapper then each div will take 33%.
```

Refer code:

```css
search-profiles-page {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin-left: 0;
  flex: .75;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin-left: 0;
  flex: .75;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  display: block;
  background: #f7fafa;
}

profile-summaries {
  display: block;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results profile-summaries .list {
  padding: 15px;
}

profile-summaries .profiles-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

search-profiles-page .xui-profile-search-results profile-summaries .list profile-summary {
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: calc(30% - 15px);
}

profile-summary {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<search-profiles-page>
  <div class="xui-profile-search-results">
    <profile-summaries>
      <div class="list">
        <profile-modals>
          <div class="profiles-container">
            <profile-summary>
              <div class="profile-header">
                blahblah
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                blahblah
              </div>
            </profile-summary>
            <profile-summary>
              <div class="profile-header">
                blahblah
              </div>
              <div class="body">
                blahblah
              </div>
            </profile-summary>
          </div>
        </profile-modals>
      </div>
    </profile-summaries>
  </div>
</search-profiles-page>
```